# How to return a nil object if there are no matches during comparison

Tags: ruby

```
foo = foos.select{|x|x.name == xval}.first.value
```

If there is no match for `xval` then it evaluates to a undefined method on `nil:NilClass`. How should I avoid this and return a `nil` object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check return result of `first` method:

```
foo = foos.select {|x| x.name == xval }.first
foo.nil? ? nil : foo.value
```

ADDED: Or use `Enumerable#find`:

```
foo = foos.find {|x| x.name == xval }
```

Comment: if this is going to be the selected answer, you should check @mu answer and change select+first to detect/find. A reference to Rails' try or Ick's maybe would be also good.

Answer (score 2):

You can clean it up a bit by skipping `select`/`first` in favor of `find`:

```
one = foos.find { |x| x.name == xval }
foo = one ? one : nil
```

And if you were in Rails, you could use `try`:

```
foo = foos.find { |x| x.name == xval }.try(:value)
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid `[].first` returning nil seems weird.

you can check if the first object really `respond_to?` a method named `value`, before invoking the method.

say, `foo_candidate.respond_to? :value` returns true if there is such method.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'ick'
foo_value = foos.detect { |foo| foo.name == xval }.maybe.value
```